# How do I find all URLs without a directory?

Tags: regex, google-search-appliance

The following expression doesn't seem to be working for me, and I can't figure out why.

```
regexpIgnoreCase:^https?://www.aaaaaaa.com/[^/]*$
```

I'm trying to select all URLs under a given domain that do not contain directories. Any advice on how to do this, and in particular, why the above doesn't work?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
regexpIgnoreCase:^https?:\/\/www.aaaaaaa.com\/[^\/]*$
```

Comment: your suggestion doesn't quite escape special characters correctly, but you certainly highlighted that I need to escape the '/' in [^/], thanks!

Comment: In the GSA admin console, use the 'Test These Patterns' button under 'Start and Block URLs' to test your patterns quickly. It's much quicker than waiting for collections etc to update.

Answer (score 0):

As the [docs](http://www.google.com/support/enterprise/static/gsa/docs/admin/70/gsa_doc_set/admin_crawl/url_patterns.html#1076127) say:

> Regular expressions...:
>
> 1. Are case sensitive unless you specify regexpIgnoreCase:
> 2. Must use two escape characters (a double backslash "\") when reserved characters are added to the regular expression.

The associated example then shows that `.`s must be escaped:

```
regexpIgnoreCase:http://www\\.Example\\.Google\\.com/.*/IMAGES/
```

So your example will probably need to look like this:

```
regexpIgnoreCase:^https?://www\\.aaaaaaa\\.com/[^/]*$
```

Comment: I tend to avoid escaping '.' and '/' for the sake of readability, unless absolutely necessary.